# How to align an element to left and in the middle of div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a very simple horizontal menu with just 2 elements but I am unable to position them in the middle left. Although elements are on the middle now but they are not left or right aligned. I want them to Margin.left:5 and margin.right:5 px. See the below screenshot and css style.
[image]

```css
.body_clr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 60px;
  
  /* ADDED to see the text */
  color:white;
}

.clear {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.col1 {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box- sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ff {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  display: table- cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left !important;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px
}


}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="body_clr">

    <div class=" col1">
      <div class="left">
        LinkButton
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Hello I am a link button
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
      <div class="ff"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
      <div class="right">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> |
        <asp:Button ID="btnSignout" runat="server" Text="Sign out" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" OnClick="btnSignout_Click" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add `text-align: right;` to your **.right** class, you would have much better results with flexbox though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use position attribute:

```
    <div class="outer-wrap">
       <div class="outer-wrap-inner">
          <a href="#" title="">Text Center</a> 
          <a href="#" title="">Text Center</a> 
         </div>
    </div>
```

```
.outer-wrap{ height: 100% ; width: 100% ; position: relative; }
.outer-wrap .outer-wrap-inner{ text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
.outer-wrap .outer-wrap-inner a{ margin: 0 5px; }
```

OR

You can use bootstrap class:

```
<div class="center-outer-wrap d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <a href="#" title="">Text Center</a> 
    <a href="#" title="">Text Center</a> 
</div>
```

```
.center-outer-wrap{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.center-outer-wrap a{ margin: 0 5px; }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.   what is flexbox or flex can you get a good tutorial link.  The time I spent to fix the issue until I got your help I could have looked at the 3 to 4 hours material.

Comment: Hi @Salma, 
check these are useful links: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

You can
Use flexbox space between elements and with align-items for the center element

```
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
```

Comment: I want right or left alignment not center.  I tried other options with align-items it did not work.